# How to get more than 0% coverage on sonarqube with service test

Tags: spring-boot, unit-testing, gradle, sonarqube, spring-boot-test

So I am using Sonarqube for the first time and I do not really know how to write a good unit test for my service class where the coverage is not 0% on sonarqube.

This is **My service class** that I want to test:

```
import com.example.demo.DTO.PartyLeaderDto;
import com.example.demo.Model.PartyLeader;
import com.example.demo.Repository.PartyLeaderRepository;
import org.modelmapper.ModelMapper;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import javax.transaction.Transactional;
import java.util.List;

@Service
@Transactional
public class PartyLeaderService {
    @Autowired
    private PartyLeaderRepository partyLeaderRepository;
    @Autowired
    ModelMapper modelMapper;
    public List<PartyLeader> listAllPartyLeaders() {
        return partyLeaderRepository.findAll();
    }

    public void savePartyLeader(PartyLeaderDto partyLeaderDto) {
        PartyLeader partyLeader = convertToEntity(partyLeaderDto);
        partyLeaderRepository.save(partyLeader);
    }

    public PartyLeaderDto getPartyLeader(Integer id) {
        PartyLeader partyLeader = partyLeaderRepository.findById(id).orElse(null);
        return convertToDto(partyLeader);
    }


    public void deletePartyLeader(Integer id) {
        partyLeaderRepository.deleteById(id);
    }
    public void deleteAllLeaders() {
        partyLeaderRepository.deleteAll();}

    private PartyLeaderDto convertToDto(PartyLeader partyLeader) {
        PartyLeaderDto partyLeaderDto = modelMapper.map(partyLeader, PartyLeaderDto.class);
        return partyLeaderDto;
    }
    private PartyLeader convertToEntity(PartyLeaderDto partyLeaderDto) {
        PartyLeader entity = new PartyLeader();
        entity.setId(partyLeaderDto.getId());
        entity.setName(partyLeaderDto.getName());
        entity.setApperance(partyLeaderDto.getApperance());

        return entity;
    }
}
```

**This is my test class so far:**

```
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public class PartyLeaderServiceTest {
    
    @Autowired
    private ModelMapper modelMapper;

    @Test
    public void whenConvertPartyLeaderEntityToPostDto_thenCorrect() {
        PartyLeader partyLeader = new PartyLeader();
        partyLeader.setId(1);
        partyLeader.setName("Josse");
        partyLeader.setApperance("Link of image");

        PartyLeaderDto partyLeaderDto = modelMapper.map(partyLeader, PartyLeaderDto.class);
        Assert.assertEquals(partyLeader.getId(), partyLeaderDto.getId());
        Assert.assertEquals(partyLeader.getName(), partyLeaderDto.getName());
        Assert.assertEquals(partyLeader.getApperance(), partyLeaderDto.getApperance());
    }

    @Test
    public void whenConvertPartyDtoToPartyEntity_thenCorrect() {
        PartyLeaderDto partyLeaderDto = new PartyLeaderDto();
        partyLeaderDto.setId(1);
        partyLeaderDto.setName("Josse");
        partyLeaderDto.setApperance("Link of image");

        PartyLeader partyLeader = modelMapper.map(partyLeaderDto, PartyLeader.class);
        Assert.assertEquals(partyLeaderDto.getId(), partyLeader.getId());
        Assert.assertEquals(partyLeaderDto.getName(), partyLeader.getName());
        Assert.assertEquals(partyLeaderDto.getApperance(), partyLeader.getApperance());
    }
}
```

This test gives 0% coverage and I think it is because I am not using the service partyLeaderService class, but I can't seem to find how it should be done. Can someone help me with 1 test and then I can figure out the rest by myself.
Thanks in advance!

**My build.gradle file**

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.4.2'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.11.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
    id "org.sonarqube" version "3.0"
    id 'jacoco'
}

group = 'com.example'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '15'

configurations {
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom annotationProcessor
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}


dependencies {
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.4.1'
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5'
    implementation('io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt:0.2')
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-mail'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    compile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation 'org.modelmapper:modelmapper:2.4.1'
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    runtimeOnly 'mysql:mysql-connector-java'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    implementation 'org.eclipse.jgit:org.eclipse.jgit:5.4.2.201908231537-r'
    /**
     * JUnit jupiter with mockito.
     */
    testCompile group: 'org.mockito', name: 'mockito-junit-jupiter', version: '2.19.0'

    testCompile group: 'org.mockito', name: 'mockito-core', version: '2.19.0'
    testCompile group: 'org.springframework.security', name: 'spring-security-test', version: '5.1.6.RELEASE'
}

sonarqube{
    properties{
        property 'sonarjava.source', '1.8'
        property 'sonar.java.coveragePlugin', 'jacoco'
        property 'sonar.jacoco.reportPaths', 'build/reports/jacoco/test/jacocoTestReport.xml'
    }
}
test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You've written a test that verifies the `ModelMapper` working correctly. Nothing wrong about that, only it's a `ModelMapperTest` and not a `PartyLeaderServiceTest`.

To test `PartyLeaderservice` you either:

- write a unit test, mocking all other dependencies

```java
public class PartyLeaderServiceTest {

    @MockitoRule
    public var mockitoRule = new MockitoRule();

    @Mock
    private PartyLeaderRepository partyLeaderRepository;

    @Mock
    private ModelMapper modelMapper;

    @InjectMocks
    private PartyLeaderService partyLeaderService; // this is like calling new PartyLeaderService(partyLeaderRepository, modelMapper); 

    @Test
    void whenSavePartyLeader_thenCorrectPartyLeaderSaved() {
        // given
        var input = PartyLeaderDto.builder()
            .name("Josse")
            .appearance("Link of image")
            .build();

        // when
        partyLeaderService.savePartyLeader(input);


        // then
        verify(partyLeaderRepository).savePartyLeader(argThat(entity -> 
                entity.getName().equals("Josse")
                && entity.getAppearance().equals("Link of image"));
    }

    @Test
    void whenGetPartyLeader_ShouldReturnCorrectLeaderData() {
        // given
        def partyLeaderEntity = PartyLeader.builder()
            .name("Josse")
            .appearance("Link of image")
            .build();
        def partyLeaderDto = PartyLeaderDto.builder()
            .name("Josse")
            .appearance("Link of image")
            .build();
        when(partyLeaderRepository.findById(3L)).thenReturn(Optional.of(partyLeaderEntity));
        when(modelMapper.map(partyLeader, PartyLeaderDto.class)).thenReturn(partyLeaderDto);

        // when
        def result = partyLeaderService.getPartyLeader(3L);

        // then
        assertEqual(result, partyLeaderDto);
    }
...

}
```

- write an integration test that operates on the real setup for `PartyLeaderService`:

```java
public class PartyLeaderServiceTest {

    @Autowired
    private PartyLeaderService partyLeaderService;

    @Autowired
    private EntityManager em;

    @Test
    void whenSavePartyLeader_thenCorrectPartyLeaderSaved() {
        // given
        var input = PartyLeaderDto.builder()
            .name("Josse")
            .appearance("Link of image")
            .build();

        // when
        partyLeaderService.savePartyLeader(input);
        def createdPartyLeader = em.createQuery("SELECT l FROM PartyLeader l", PartyLeader.class).getSingleResult();

        // then
        assertEqual(createdPartyLeader.getName(), "Josse");
        assertEqual(createdPartyLeader.getAppearance(), "Link of image");
    }

    @Test
    void whenGetPartyLeader_ShouldReturnCorrectLeaderData() {
        // given
        def partyLeaderEntity = PartyLeader.builder()
            .name("Josse")
            .appearance("Link of image")
            .build();
        entityManager.persist(partyLeaderEntity); // or use @SqlScript to insert initial data into the db
        entityManager.flush();

        // when
        def result = partyLeaderService.getPartyLeader(partyLeaderEntity.getId());

        // then
        assertEqual(createdPartyLeader.getName(), "Josse");
        assertEqual(createdPartyLeader.getAppearance(), "Link of image");
    }
...

}
```

- create a mix of the two approaches, e.g. in the unit test, you could've decided you want to mock `partyLeaderRepository`, but use the actual implementation of `ObjectMapper`, because mocking it is too much effort.

Which option to choose mostly depends on a couple of factors:

- whether the logic of the component you're testing is very complex (if so, use a unit test; on the other hand, if the component only calls other components - especially third party ones, an integration test is probably more valuable)
- ROTI (how much effort you put in writing/maintaining the test vs the level of confidence it gives you, e.g. with an integration test, you can test whether transactional boundaries work correctly, for example; however, you need to spin up the application context, make sure all the other components are in the correct state, maintain an initial DB script etc.)
- desired scope of the test (unit tests test one component only, while all the other dependencies are mocked so that they behave predictably; the example integration test, on the other hand, might also fail in certain situations if either `ModelMapper` or `PartyLeaderRepository` is broken)

A common rule of thumb is to write several unit tests for a complex-logic component, testing all the possible paths, and one or two integration tests (e.g. one happy and one alternative path) to verify everything works when you connect the components together.

Comment: Thanks for your code. I have a question tho. In this line of code you wrote: 
when(partyLeaderRepository.findById(3L)).thenReturn(leader); you return leader, but this is not set anywhere. What do you mean with leader?

Comment: Now I am getting this error: PartyLeaderServiceMockTest.java:51: error: incompatible types: ArgumentMatcher is not a functional interface
        verify(partyLeaderRepository).save(argThat(entity ->

Comment: Also I get this error which I cannot seem to fix: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'java.lang.AutoCloseable org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations.openMocks(java.lang.Object)'

I added my build.gradle file in the post:

Comment: This is a completely unrelated issue. Please ask a separate question.

Comment: I did, but no reaction so far